# std::stringstream's seekg does not work after while loop

Tags: c++, c++17, stringstream

I have this `std::stringstream` object whose contents I have to read (only) twice. For this I thought I could use its `seekg` member function to repeat the reading. But I can't make it work. Here's a MWE that reproduces the issues I'm having (adapted from the example [in the docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg)).

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    const char *str = "Hello, world";
    std::stringstream ss(str);

    std::string word1 = "asdf";
    std::string word2 = "qwer";
    std::string word3 = "zxcv";
    std::string word4 = "yuio";

    ss >> word1;
    ss.seekg(0); // rewind
    ss >> word2;
    while (ss >> word3) { }
    ss.seekg(0); // rewind
    ss >> word4;

    std::cout << "word1 = " << word1 << '\n'
              << "word2 = " << word2 << '\n'
              << "word3 = " << word3 << '\n'
              << "word4 = " << word4 << '\n';
}
```

I expect the contents to be:

```
word1 = Hello,
word2 = Hello,
word3 = world
word4 = Hello,
```

since the call `ss.seekg(0)` after the while loop should put `ss` at the beginning of its contents. Why do I not get the expected output, but rather this?

```
word1 = Hello,
word2 = Hello,
word3 = world
word4 = yuio
```

This means that `word4` is never updated, thus the statement `ss >> word4` has no effect. But in this case, then the `ss.seekg(0)` does not have any effect either.

Is the while loop causing the `ss` object to fail to "rewind"? Perhaps the `ss` tried to read too much and now is in an error state (I have no idea).

How can I fix this? That is, how can I make the statement `ss >> word4` read `Hello,`?

I'm using `g++ (Ubuntu 11.1.0-1ubuntu1~20.04) 11.1.0` on C++17.

Comment: The `while` loop ends when the stream is in an error state because the code attempted to read beyond the end of the input. That error state is persistent; if further operations on the stream are appropriate, the code should clear the error state: `ss.clear()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`seekg` first constructs and checks the sentry object (used by cppstreams to represent any stream failure), if that sentry object represents any failure then the function just returns without doing anything.

After the while loop, `ss`'s `failbit` and `eofbit` will be set. The call to seekg will behave as described before (won't do anything).

For `seekg` to take any affect, you will have to clear the failure bits by calling `ss.clear()`before calling `seekg` itself after the while loop. Then, the sentry object won't represent any failure and `seekg` will behave as expected.

Relevant links:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt2

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg

Comment: If compiling to C++11 or better the EOF bit should not be a problem because, as of C++11, `seekg` clears EOF before seeking. Other failures you're still stuck with.

Comment: I knew a few things about those bits but I did not know they could be cleared without having to reconstruct the whole `std::stringstream`. Thanks!